# How can I scan using nmap and Zenmap all hostnames that begin with a particular string?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, network-monitoring, nmap

I have a number of nodes on a couple of networks whose hostnames all start with `org`. Some examples are:

- orgwebsvr1
- orgwebsvr2
- orgwebsvr3
- orgdbsvrmysql
- orgdbsvrmssql
- orgdbsvrosql

With nmap, I know that I can scan multiple targets using the IP or an external list.  But I want to discover all the devices on a network that start with `org`.  Is there such a way to write that using nmap?

Thank you.

Comment: your examples do not all start with org

Comment: You're right.  I just fixed that.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the hosts all have valid DNS entries, you can do a list scan querying the DNS for each host on your target network, then filter the output to a file and use it as target for a second nmap scan:

`nmap -sL 192.168.0.0/24  | awk '{print $5}' | grep ^org  > ~/targets.txt; nmap -iL ~/targets.txt`

Comment: A more accurate command: `nmap -sL -oG - 192.168.0.0/24 | awk '$3~/^(org/{print $2}' | nmap -iL -`; This will only check hostnames, not other output, and will pipe directly to the second nmap instance.

Comment: I like your command more, but it needs an extra escape to the awk command: `nmap -sL -oG - 192.168.0.0/24 | awk '$3~/^\(org/{print $2}' | nmap -iL -`

Comment: Thanks, I always forget between awk, sed, grep, and vi which syntax must be escaped.

Comment: This is incredible, thank you.  What would be the equivalent in a Windows machine?  If there is none, you need a programming language like Perl, how would you do it Perl?  Thank you.

Comment: I'm not looking for something downloading sed, awk, or grep for Windows.  Those are fine, but I'd prefer something innate like PowerShell or Perl.

Answer (score 2):

Three routes to handle this, not related to NMAP directly.

1. If you have an inventory system (or directory) of hosts, you
   should be able to query that to find your related IP addresses.
2. Since you manage DNS assumably for this network, you should be able
   to access your nameserver details to find all A (host) records that match your pattern and
   get the associated IP addresses.
3. Manually scan all DNS PTR (reverse) records across your IP space and find the hosts you care about using a simple regex like /^org/ (if you have reverse DNS records setup).

In all cases, you then can pass the resulting IPs to NMAP to conduct your scan (unless you were just wanting to use NMAP for the discovery portion and not actual scans).