# Need equivalent of command with nmap, awk and grep for Windows machines with PowerShell and/or Perl

Tags: windows, powershell, perl, nmap, awk

Please see this thread for reference

[How can I scan using nmap and Zenmap all hostnames that begin with a particular string?](https://serverfault.com/questions/490079/how-can-i-scan-using-nmap-and-zenmap-all-hostnames-that-begin-with-a-particular)

One of the answers in the thread above uses the following query (I take no credit at all for the command):

> nmap -sL -oG - 192.168.0.0/24 | awk '$3~/^(org/{print $2}' | nmap -iL -`

It scans all nodes for hostnames starting with **org** and returns a list of matching nodes.

It works great in a Unix/Linux environment, but I need an equivalent for Windows.  I'd prefer not to use awk, sed, or grep packages for Windows.  I'd like to maintain a standard and use PowerShell and/or Perl.

Is there an equivalent way to construct this query using PowerShell and/or Perl, along with nmap?

Comment: You've [not accepted any answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) on the original question. Did none of the answers work for that one?

Comment: Thank you.  I just accepted it a moment ago, since it does work (very well) in linux/unix environments.  But I need an equivalent for Windows-based systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nmap parts of that command should work the same. To convert the `awk` command to Perl, use:

```
perl -lane "print $F[1] if $F[2]=~/^\(org/"
```

(Because of quoting differences between Windows cmd.exe and most *nix shells, *nix shells should use single quotes instead of double)

To do the same in PowerShell, this should work (not tested):

```
%{ if ($_.Split()[2] -match "^\(org") { $_.Split()[1]; } }
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I appreciate it.  The Perl version works great. But I'm getting an error in PowerShell: `Bad argument to operator '-match': parsing "^(r" - Not Enough )'s..`

Comment: I had to change the powershell version slightly to clear the error: `%{ if ($_.Split()[2] -match "^\(org") { $_.Split()[1]; } }`.  I just added a backslash before the parenthesis in the regex and changed the array index in the output.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user717236 Thanks for the corrections. I've applied them in the answer above.